# Php & code injection

Tags: javascript, php, code-injection

The website for a client of mine continues to be "hacked" (I didn't do the website).The hacked pages contain a js script that loads an image and audio from youtube (Lol). Every page was modified and every page has a "news banner" .I'm pretty sure the problem is this part

```
    <?php 
$ul = new NewsList; 
$ul->Load(3); 
if($ul->Current() == null){ ?> 
<?php   } 
else{ 
for(; $ul->Current() != null; $ul->Next()){ 
$new = $ul->Current();
```

the complete implementation of this NewsList : http://pastebin.com/WuWjcJ4p

I'm not a php programmer so I don't get where the problem is....I'm not asking that someone going to explain every line, maybe only an advice , thank you

Comment: This does not look like the source of the described behavior. It’s accessing the database – or has that been compromised, too?

Comment: probably the script got inserted into the database. you'll need to check the database

Comment: scripts can get inserted if you don't clean your content before inserting into the db

Comment: @Gumbo Yes,I know it's totally crazy but the "web designer"  thought that storing news into db is a good idea. The website was hacked

Comment: Gumbo Yes,I know it's totally crazy but the "web designer"  thought that storing news into db is a good idea. The website was hacked 3/4 times,in the first one I found junk news into db; after that I commented the php part (what a desperate noob I am...) and changed password of everything: db ,ftp ,webspace ecc   @Loïc thank you so much, I wasn' expecting someone write code,thank you again! News cannot be commented, simply the news is a longtext in db,so if you add to db the php page shows it (here's db) http://imgur.com/4uChIyV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an SQL injection.

I believe the loadById() method is injectable (depending on how you call it).

Here is a way to strengthen it :

```
    function LoadById($id){
            $this->news = array();
            $this->current = 0;
            $this->total = 0;

            $ndb = new NewsDB('news');
            $result = $ndb->_query("SELECT * FROM ".$ndb->table." WHERE id = " . intval($id));
            $new = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $n = new News($new['id'], $new['titolo'], $new['data'], $new['contenuto'], $new['img']);
            array_push($this->news, $n);
            unset($n);

            $this->total = 1;
    }
```

Someone might have stolen the passwords from administration using this security flaw and edited the articles from the back-office.

So I suggest you change this code, then change the passwords, delete all php sessions, and finally edit your articles to remove this "news banner".

Note that it might as well be a stored XSS.
Do you have a system which allows to comment the news?